# Using data.table to extract value from a column who's name matches a value within a loop of multiple data.frames

Tags: r, data.table

I am working with GPS locations that occurred in a given time period "dateperiod". I want to use the value in one row (dateperiod), look in the column for that dateperiod, and extract the value (distance to disturbance) for whatever row I am working in. But I also am doing this within a loop that goes through multiple disturbance dataframes. Dummy data set:

Example Basic data (data_basic_DT):

```
structure(list(EndId = 1:9, dateperiod = c(141101L, 141101L, 
141101L, 141101L, 141101L, 141101L, 141101L, 141101L, 141101L
)), .Names = c("EndId", "dateperiod"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Example disturbance data 1 (low_roads):

```
structure(list(EndId = 1:9, dateperiod = c(141101L, 141101L, 
141101L, 141101L, 141101L, 141101L, 141101L, 141101L, 141101L
), `151101` = c(710.211, 684.471, 676.831, 762.955, 704.06, 674.685, 
682.495, 686.586, 696.348), `150501` = c(710.211, 684.471, 676.831, 
762.955, 704.06, 674.685, 682.495, 686.586, 696.348), `141101` = c(710.211, 
684.471, 676.831, 762.955, 704.06, 674.685, 682.495, 686.586, 
696.348), `140501` = c(710.211, 684.471, 676.831, 762.955, 704.06, 
674.685, 682.495, 686.586, 696.348), `131101` = c(710.211, 684.471, 
676.831, 762.955, 704.06, 674.685, 682.495, 686.586, 696.348), 
    `130501` = c(710.211, 684.471, 676.831, 762.955, 704.06, 
    674.685, 682.495, 686.586, 696.348), `121101` = c(710.211, 
    684.471, 676.831, 762.955, 704.06, 674.685, 682.495, 686.586, 
    696.348)), .Names = c("EndId", "dateperiod", "151101", "150501", 
"141101", "140501", "131101", "130501", "121101"), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Ex disturbance data 2 (high_roads):

```
structure(list(EndId = 1:9, dateperiod = c(141101L, 141101L, 
141101L, 141101L, 141101L, 141101L, 141101L, 141101L, 141101L
), `151101` = c(806.415, 802.56, 502.35, 1234.2, 704.06, 685.23, 
682.495, 1002.3, 696.348), `150501` = c(710.211, 684.471, 676.831, 
762.955, 704.06, 802.56, 502.35, 1234.2, 696.348), `141101` = c(710.211, 
130.25, 453.25, 762.955, 704.06, 674.685, 682.495, 686.586, 696.348
), `140501` = c(710.211, 684.471, 802.56, 502.35, 1234.2, 674.685, 
682.495, 686.586, 696.348), `131101` = c(710.211, 684.471, 676.831, 
762.955, 704.06, 674.685, 502.35, 1234.2, 704.06), `130501` = c(710.211, 
684.471, 676.831, 762.955, 704.06, 674.685, 682.495, 686.586, 
696.348), `121101` = c(502.35, 1234.2, 704.06, 762.955, 704.06, 
674.685, 682.495, 686.586, 696.348)), .Names = c("EndId", "dateperiod", 
"151101", "150501", "141101", "140501", "131101", "130501", "121101"
), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000006640788>)
```

So, for each EndId, I want it to look at the dateperiod, see that it is 141101 in this example, look at column "141101", extract the value, and put it in a new column. Within a loop that goes through low_roads and high_roads.

Thanks to some help (below), I have it working much faster than before, with this:

```
disturbancelist <- list(low_roads=low_roads, high_roads=high_roads) #Lists all the disturbance dataframes
for (d in disturbancelist){ 
  ##Create a column named by the current disturbance class
     Class<-d$Class[2] ##calls the disturbance type
  ##Merge basic data and each disturbance dateframe to get the right distance values
  mergeex<-merge(data_basic_DT, d, by.x = "EndId", by.y = "EndId", all.y == FALSE)
  mergeexdf<-as.data.frame(mergeex)
  col.names<-names(mergeexdf)
  mergeexdf$distance <- mergeexdf[cbind(1:nrow(mergeexdf), fmatch(mergeexdf$dateperiod, col.names))]
  names(data_basic_DT)[names(data_basic_DT)=="distance"] <- Class ##Change name of column to current disturbance class
  print(Class)
}
```

Now, I would like to change this code to work in data.tables to make it run faster. It works outside of the loop as data.tables, but not within. Any help appreciated!

Comment: This post is too long and lacking in reproducibility for me to read, but I think (based on Brian's answer), this might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33310179/select-values-from-different-columns-based-on-a-variable-containing-column-names

Comment: You need to provide sample data in a format that people can copy-paste in.  (Use `dput` to get correct format with subset of data).  Posting tab/space deliminated tables doesn't help anyone.  You also can't post example code that refers to variables that aren't defined for people to actually execute your sample code.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question to be more explicate, concise (hopefully), and provide reproducible examples. Note I also updated based on an answer provided below.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, this sounds similar to a question I asked a while back:
[R data.frame get value from variable which is selected by another variable, vectorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35277274/r-data-frame-get-value-from-variable-which-is-selected-by-another-variable-vect). Although that question applies to data.frames in general, <s>I think it is still a good solution for a data.table.</s> EDIT: Maybe not, based on responses, but it does work well on data.frames at least.

The idea is to use `match` with the `names` attribute to get the numeric indices of the columns for each row, and then use that to get the value. Something like this, for a data.frame called `df`:

```
df$newvar <- df[cbind(1:nrow(df), match(df$dateperiod, names(df)))]
```

Where the first number `1:nrow(df)` basically takes the place of your `for` loop and the second number `match(df$dateperiod, names(df))` identifies the column whose name matches the value contained in `dateperiod` for each row. It works because `match` operates on the entire column vector `df$dateperiod` and returns a column of the same length.

Hope that helps.

Comment: If you have a data.table you want to use the fast joins that package offers and not the rather slow (in comparison) base function match.

Comment: Thank you, I got that working nicely and quickly with dataframes but not data.tables. It messes up when calling in the different data.tables while looping, i.e. names(dt). I edited the question to reflect this improvement.